# Change an array of arrays to just an array to avoid ==> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Tags: python, arrays

In response to the questions below, I'm offering additional clarification...

I have an array of arrays, one column of 81 sub-arrays (81 rows).  I think this equates to shape (81, 1).  Each sub-array is an array with 8 elements (1 row of 8 elements).  I believe this equates to shape of (1, 8).  I created this array of arrays using the .append function:

```
row = (["str1", "str2", "str3", "str4", "str5", "str6", "str7", "str8"])
if ((row[clm_number] == best_one_value_predictor_list[1]):           
        one_predictor_exception_array.append(row)
```

To access elements in the sub-array I have use the following code:

```
anchor_column_array = one_predictor_exception_array[:][0]
```

instead of

```
anchor_column_array = one_predictor_exception_array[:,anchor_column_index]
```

My goal is to create an array of shape (81, 8) so I no longer have sub-arrays.  I realize that appending an array to an array creates this situation but I'd like to get to a simpler data structure.  Previously, I had sucked in a csv file that was (81,8)

```
io.read_csv_into_array("train.C.csv")
```

The type of answer I'm looking for is either a) a way to append rows of data to an array without create an array of arrays (or lists) or b) a way to reshape an array of arrays to just be an simple single array.  I want the final shape to be (X, Y) and i'm able to access it using [:,index]

The first two elements in each sub-array are unique so I can just blend all the arrays.  I need them to stack just like they were an (81, 8) spreadsheet.

Comment: When you say you want an array of shape (81, 8), that sounds like it would have sub-arrays (which you say you don't want).  Do you want an array with 648 elements?

Comment: No--I want the array to still have shape of (81, 8) but each row is not itself a new array, it's just a row in the array so I can access it by [:, Y]

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what you want to store in the arrays or what you want to do with the data.  If you want to store numbers, do math, and index your arrays as x[:,i] (as you indicate), then you are probably looking for [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), which isn't in the standard library.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> mylist = [[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6]]
>>> myarray = numpy.array(mylist)
>>> myarray[:,0]
numpy.array([1,4])
```

Even if your interest isn't solely number, numpy arrays can store any of the python built-in types including object.

```
>>> a = numpy.array([['a', 'b', 'c'],
                     ['d', 'e', 'f']])
array([['a', 'b', 'c'],
       ['d', 'e', 'f'], dtype='|S1')
```

The type of the elements of the array are indicated by the array's numpy [dtype](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) attribute.  You can even have "compound" types that mix built-in types.

```
>>> a = numpy.array([[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)],
                     [('d', 4), ('e', 5), ('f', 6)]],
                     dtype='S1, i4')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not just numbers, I'm storing unique string values in each row.

Comment: @user2788015: numpy can handle strings, either as fixed-length or as references to Python objects.

Comment: @user278801 As Blckknght says, it can store more than numbers.  I've edited my answer to show this.

Answer (score 0):

You can `extend` arrays :

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a.extend([5, 6, 7, 8])
```

`extend` assumes the argument is an iterable, and `append` each of its element to the source array.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was actually appending a list into another list instead of an array into an array.  I converted the list of lists into an array and my problem was solved.

Beginner problem

Comment: Could you update your question with the code you used to "covert the list of lists into an array?"  I'm not sure what you're saying here.